# Selenium web driver icon state identification

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Currently I am stuck at identifying the state of the icon.

I have a icon which have 2 states, locked and unlocked and changed on clicked on that icon.
 I know to find element by class name or X path but the real issue is I need to know what is the current state of the icon. When I inspect on the icon , i get the code as below and I don't know which refer to current state of the class.

```
<span class="x-towbook-lock locked" title="Locked by accounting bot1">  
  <i class="fas fa-lock" onclick="CallsTabs.updateLockStatus(21108183, true, event);"></i>                             
  <i class="fas fa-lock-open" onclick="CallsTabs.updateLockStatus(21108183, false, event);"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have captured the HTML when the *icon* depicted **locked** state.

To identify the state of the icon you can write a method to find the *icon state* and you can use the following solution:

```
public void FindIconState() 
{
    String IconClasses = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'x-towbook-lock')]")).GetAttribute("class");
    if (IconClasses.Contains("locked"))
         Console.WriteLine("Icon state is LOCKED");
    else
         Console.WriteLine("Icon state is UNLOCKED");
}
```

Now you can call this method anytime from anywhere within your program:

```
FindIconState();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the state using **getAttribute()** method.

Consider the following example  :

```
WebElement element  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='x-towbook-lock locked']"));
if(element.getAttribute("class").contains("locked")){
// Locked State .  
// do something 
}else{
// Unlocked State. 
// do something 
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Glad it helped .I hope you won't mind giving it an upvote . Also please mark the answer as accepted. It really motivates people to contribute towards community :)

Answer (score 0):

To get current state of the icon you can check if `locked` exist in css class attribute:

```
public bool IsLocked()
{
    String cssClass = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.x-towbook-lock")).GetAttribute("class");
    return Array.IndexOf(cssClass.Split(' '), "locked") > -1;
}
```